# Why is there no definition of the constant pi in the C++11 standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, pi, std

I find it quiet annoying that I have to use the macro `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` in order to get the value of pi into my program. Or I need to define it myself in one of my own headers. Or I have to use boost and all that.

It just annoys me, that there isn't a standard c++ header defining that constant in a portable way. Is there any particular reason that math constants like pi are not in the c++ standard? Could it be in one of the next versions of the standard?

Comment: it's annoying but required. Just add `_USE_MATH_DEFINES` into compiler option so you can avoid add it from header. This is the best solution I can suggest

Comment: There is always [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/math/doc/html/math_toolkit/constants.html)

Comment: Except that the macro is `_XOPEN_SOURCE` (which must be defined as 700), and the constant is `M_PI`.  (Which in itself is the strongest argument in favor of standardization.)

Comment: The reason the C++ committee didn't add it is because `<math.h>` belongs to the C committee.  Why the C committee didn't add it?  You got me.

Comment: The next version of the C standard is slated for 2022 so any change will be a long wait [C - Preliminary C2x Charter](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2021.htm)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I would assume its not standardized because its not really a major concern. I really do not see any hassle in just writing down a #define or const static, or just making a header with a bunch of math constants you may need. Its not really anything anyone composing the standard has on his mind while trying to improve the language.

Comment: Surely it's bad to hard code it yourself because it may change...

Comment: @BoBTFish One possible way to avoid errors is to use `double pi = 4 * std::atan(1.0);`

Comment: @BoBTFish I would bet obnoxious sums of money that the value of the mathematical constant `π` is not going to change any time soon ;-)

Comment: @BoBTFish: Of course, constants like pi change all the time. I think the better argument is that not everyone may need the constants to the same precision.

Comment: @ilent2: I'd be rather disappointed if it weren't a compile-time constant.

Comment: Incidentally, this is used as a leading example in Gabriel Dos Reis' [Variable Templates proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3651.pdf).

Comment: You can't (portably) define it yourself, because you don't know how many digits you might need.

Comment: For what it's worth, please take a look at http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3651.pdf, proposal voted into the next standard. The first example is a template definition of pi, for all types to which the double literal representing pi is convertible. Maybe they just waited to have sufficient expressive power in the language.